# AP Physics C Mechanics Work/Energy/Forces Pulley Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

I was wondering why the answer to the following question is A. I understand that the net work on m1 and m2 are both positive (net force and motion are in the same direction), but I do not know how to tell which one is more positive than the other.

[image: Why is the answer A?]

Comment: Hint: $W_\text{net}=\Delta K$, $m_1>m_2$, and the blocks always have the same speed.

Comment: @Aaron but what about gravitational potential energy change.

Comment: @Ramanujan_π It's covered in there already. $W_\text{net}=W_\text{grav}+W_{tension}=-\Delta U+W_\text{tension}$. But since it's just asking about total work there really is no need to even think about potential energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the blocks are moving together, they must have the same acceleration $a$ (in magnitude), and also move the same distance $d$. The work on block $i$ is $W_i = F_i d = m_i a d$, so we just need to know which of $m_1$ and $m_2$ is greater. Since $m_1$ is moving downwards, even when held back by both $m_2$ and the slope's normal and friction forces, intuition says that $m_1$ must be larger. To prove it, consider the forces on $m_1$ like in Leo Liu's answer.

Comment: Thanks! I was boxed in by my incorrect thinking that I couldn't assume the masses as they weren't given.

Comment: That also confused me at first!